# R PCA: Why are some points in a biplot larger than others?

Tags: r, visualization, pca, factoextra, biplot

Why are some points in a PCA biplot larger than others? Unfortunately, I couldn't find an explanation in the help documentation.

Example:

```
# Load required library
library(factoextra)

# Perform PCA using prcomp
iris_pca <- prcomp(iris[, 1:4], scale. = TRUE)

# Create a biplot
fviz_pca_biplot(iris_pca, 
                habillage = iris$Species)
```

[image]

Comment: the large points are the group means for each PC.  you can remove them with `mean.point=FALSE` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is not a size scale, but the mean of each group. This seem to be documented only in `factoextra::fviz`, not the wrappers. Elsewhere this is passed via `...` to `ggpubr::ggscatter`, which has the following argument that `factoextra` sets to `TRUE` by default:

> `mean.point` logical value. If `TRUE`, group mean points are added to the plot.

Can be disabled like so:

```r
fviz_pca_biplot(iris_pca, 
                habillage = iris$Species,
                mean.point = FALSE)
```

[image: biplot]